# JMail.SMTPMail not working ("Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad' ActiveX component can't create object")

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, jmail

I am sending mail from ASP page using below code

```
Dim MyMail
Set MyMail = Server.CreateObject("JMail.SMTPMail")
MyMail.ServerAddress = ""
MyMail.Sender = "senderemail"
MyMail.AddRecipient  "mail@mail.com"    
MyMail.Subject = "Inquiry "
MyMail.Body = "<p>This is a response</p>"
MyMail.ContentType = "text/html" 
MyMail.Execute
Set MyMail=nothing
```

but its is not working.
I am getting below error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad' ActiveX component can't create object

Comment: Is the JMail DLL/component registered properly?

Comment: Actually, that error is listed in the JMail FAQ... Did you Google? http://support.activeservers.com/components//Jmail/jmail_faq.htm

Comment: @Rich i have go through that also.
and in line 3 it says
Copy JMail.dll to the system32 directory. (ie C:\WINNT\System32\) , but i don't have JMail.dll Can you please tell me from where to download JMail.dll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to [enable 32-bit Applications to true in the application pool](http://forums.iis.net/t/1147232.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have that component installed (or not registered correctly). Try the built-in `CDO.Message` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17425519/1630171) for an example.

Comment: i have tried that also, and i am not getting any error. but i didn't get any mail either.

Comment: Try running the code from a "normal" VBScript. If that too doesn't produce any error, check the logs of the mail server.