# How do you send an email through port 80?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a vbs code that e-mails some text but the network here is blocking port 25 is there a way of doing this through port 80 or some way to send a message through port 80 at least.

I got this error code when I tried: 80040213

Here is my code:

```
dim strSMTPFrom, strSMTPTo, strSMTPRelay, strTextBody, strSubject, oMessage
strSMTPFrom = "email@gmail.com"
strSMTPTo = "email@gmail.com"
strSMTPRelay = "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
strTextBody = "test"
strSubject = "test"
Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configurati on/sendusing") = 2
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPRelay
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configurati on/smtpserverport") = 25
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
oMessage.Subject = strSubject
oMessage.From = strSMTPFrom
oMessage.To = strSMTPTo
oMessage.TextBody = strTextBody
oMessage.Send
```

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: Have you tried to send a mail via web page in browser?

Comment: do you mean i should just go to gmail.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays most ISPs block outgoing connections to port 25 in an attempt to fight botnet spam. There are 2 customary ways of dealing with this:

- Send the mail through the ISP's mail servers (if the ISP provides a mail gateway for its customers).
- Send the mail to a mail submission server hosted by yourself or your mail provider via an [(authenticated) connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28605803/1630171) to port 587 (submission) or port 465 (smtps, deprecated).

Technically you can send mail via port 80 if you set up a mail server that accepts mail on that port. Doing so isn't common (or recommended) practice, though.

Comment: how do i do the second thing you said

Comment: it still doesn't work for me it says that it cant connect to the server

Comment: a way to send a message without using gmail is fine too

Comment: Haha sorry for never selecting this as the answer