# Monitoring service with WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I would like to monitor some services with WMI: 
1. Test if the service is running
2. If not running restart it
3. If I can't restart it send an email

Could someone help me deal with this please?

```
strComputer = "." 
srv= " WSearch, wuauserv "

Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
"winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where Name='srv'") 
For Each objService in colItems
Wscript.Echo "Service Name: " & objService.Name & VBNewLine _
    & "State: " & objService.State

     if objService.State="Stopped"  then
     objService.StartService()
    Wscript.Echo "Started service " 
    else 
    REM here the code for email if the service didn't start
 end if         
Next
```

Comment: Does what you have so work properly? Does it start the service if it's not already running?

Comment: If your question is how to send an e-mail, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17425519/1630171).

Comment: Would it be easier to use PowerShell?