# Crash when user clicks DENY

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010, hta

I am running this VBScript inside an HTA application:

```
Sub CustomMailMessage()
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    objMail.Recipients.Add("myemail@domain.com") ' crashing here if deny
    objMail.Subject = UCase("Phone Correction")
    objMail.HTMLBody = GenerateEmailBody
    objMail.Body = "My New Number Is: "
    objMail.Display
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.SendKeys "^+{END}", True
    WshShell.SendKeys "{END}", True
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

A popup appears asking the user to click `ALLOW` or `DENY`.

If `ALLOW` is clicked, my script works. If `DENY` is clicked, it crashes.

Is there a way to do one of the following:

1. Not crash and exit gracefully.
2. Suppress the Outlook warning and create the message (preferred).

All the Mail clients are Outlook 2010 running on Windows XP or Windows 7.

Comment: Use [CDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17425519/1630171) instead of Outlook.

Comment: We need to have a record that the mail was sent from their account in their sent folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either install an up-to-date version of antivirus software (if you can control the client environment) or bypass the Outlook Object Model (e.g. using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) - I am its author).

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for your options.

Comment: Already using Symantec (Corporate Edition). Can't change settings since it's managed from the server. Does Redemption need to be installed on every client that will use the HTA application?

Comment: Yes, Redemption needs to be installed on the machine where the code is executed.